# How to get the checkbox values in PHP if they all have the same name

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding multiple html checkboxes with the same name to URL using $_GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982235/adding-multiple-html-checkboxes-with-the-same-name-to-url-using-get)

I have the following code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function toggle(source) {
      checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo[]');
      for(var i in checkboxes)
      checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
</script>

<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Toggle All<br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar1"> Bar 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar2"> Bar 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar3"> Bar 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar4"> Bar 4<br/>
```

I just want to ask how will I able to get all the values on the checkboxes that are checked using PHP?

Comment: I just used the code above and once I checked the checkbox with onclick event, all of the other checkboxes are also checked. so i think it's working. sorry for my bad english XD

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure I'm understanding you but here's my impression:

You need to use an input array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar1"> Bar 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar2"> Bar 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar3"> Bar 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar4"> Bar 4<br/>
```

Otherwise you're just assigning the last occurrence that is valid as the posted input.

Comment: That will break the javascript... So this is not a valid solution.

Comment: Sir I changed it now but I don't know how to get the values from the checkboxes that are checked

Comment: @AlanFoster: surely the solution to that is to fix the JS too? `:)`

Comment: @Alan - yeah you're right. He would have to loop through them. Still though, for processing - this is how he will get the values checked in php.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process multiple boxes give each one a name ending with "[]" to create an array.

Only the values of the checked boxes will be sent to the php script:

```
// $_REQUEST['foo'] will return an array of the values
echo join(',', $_REQUEST['foo']);
```